# how to show time series data in bokeh as a step chart

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, bokeh

is there a way to plot a time series (e.g. pandas data frame i.e. using datetime as index) as a step chart in bokeh? I cannot find any document for this, anyone with any experience? thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get a **date-time x-axis**, you can provide a `pandas.Series` with `DatetimeIndex` as the data source. As of 0.12.2 and probably earlier, the x-axis will automatically be given a datetime type.

It's important the index be `DatetimeIndex`. In the following example, if the index were set column `Year`, the result would be an `Int64Index` instead and the x-axis would display ticks like `1985.5` as you zoom in.

*Examples*

```
from bokeh.sampledata import unemployment1948
import pandas as pd    

df = unemployment1948.data
df['ts'] = df.Year.apply(lambda yr: pd.to_datetime('%d0101T0000' % yr))
df.set_index('ts', inplace=True)
```

Provide just one series and the index is figured out automatically:

[image]

Provide a dictionary with names for keys and Series for values to plot multiple lines:

> *This plot also zoomed in to show ticks are date-based.*

[image]

Or use a separate datasource dictionary and specify the `.values` of corresponding `Series` and `DatetimeIndex`es:

[image]